# Memory leak in a process which dynamically loads various plugins

Tags: memory, plugins, memory-leaks, valgrind, dlopen

There is a process *process1*, which does `dl_open` (dynamic load/unload) of various libraries. Let's call these libraries as plugins (*plugin1*, *plugin2*, *plugin3* ...),

Now I can see memory leak in *process1* using valgrind(and likewise). But I want to identify, the exact plugin which could have contributed (majorily) to the leak. Is there an easy way to do this? and other than a) Running each plugin as a separate process

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you run an application under Valgrind memcheck with leak detection enabled it will dump the leak stats when the application terminates.

There are two mechanisms you can use to make memcheck run a leak dump at other times during execution.

1. Use the Valgrind client communication macros to instrument your code
2. Use vgdb commands

I wrote an [article covering this](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1905) a few years ago.

As an example you might have something like this in your code

```
dlclose(myHandle);
VALGRIND_DO_LEAK_CHECK;
```

Comment: To have better stack traces when using dlclose, it is good to use --keep-debuginfo=yes.